# Loopback 4 extract raw body of POST request

Tags: loopback4

For a hashing and verification purpose, raw body (without parsing) of a `application/json` post request is needed.
Does loopback 4 provide any method for that? `Request.body` is parsed as a json.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the raw body by providing the following `requestBodySpec`:

```js
  @post('/raw-body-post')
  async rawBodyPost(
    @requestBody({
      description: 'Raw Body',      // Description can be anything
      required: true,
      content: {
        'application/json': {       // Make sure this matches the POST request type
          'x-parser': 'raw',        // This is the key to skipping parsing
          schema: {type: 'object'},
        },
      },
    }) body: Buffer
  ) {
    const rawBody = body.toString('utf8');
    ...
  }
```